# No Sorted Neighborhood Algorithm in R?

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am currently looking into ways to detect duplicate records in data sets using R. I tried to find some implementation of a Sorted Neighborhood Algorithm along the lines of Hernandez/Stolfo (1998), without success. I did find package [RecordLinkage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf) which I still need to explore more deeply. It looks like an implementation of the Fellegi/Sunter approach. However it doesn't feature Sorted Neighborhood methods. Am I getting something wrong here or is there really no R implementation of a Sorted Neighborhood method?

EDIT_1: by "duplicate records" I mean records that may differ slightly but do refer to the same entity, e.g. first and last names might be exchanged, there might be typos etc.

Comment: Please note that questions asking for software recommendations aren't exactly on-topic on SO. Do you know any implementations of this algorithm ion other languages? It might be possible to interface R with them.

Comment: If you just want "to detect duplicate records in data sets"  use `?duplicated`.

Comment: @nicola: thanks for the comment. I wasn't clear enough here, see EDIT_1 above. I know the function ?duplicated and am already using it, but it doesn't go far enough here..

Comment: @RalfStubner: thanks for your input and sorry, didn't want to be off topic! I am just wondering how to solve that particular problem with R. In case there really is no existing solution which I can hardly believe, I will write my own procedure... I don't know about implementations in other languages, but I assume there are some..

Comment: One possibility would be to use the Python package `recordlinkage` via `reticulate`: https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref-index.html#recordlinkage.index.SortedNeighbourhood. I haven't tried that, though.